# Why "Hyper-V Platform" feature is disabled?

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v, requirements

I tried to enable Hyper-v feature in Windows 8 Pro,

but "Hyper-V Platform feature is Disabled" ...

I get this message:
hyper-v cannot be installed the processor does not have required virtualization capabilities

my processor : Core i7-3630QM

and this information by "systeminfo"

> ```
> Hyper-V Requirements: VM Monitor Mode Extensions: No
>                       Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
>                       Second Level Address Translation: Yes
>                       Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
> ```

What problem is my computer does not support this feature?

Comment: *Hyper-V Requirements: VM Monitor Mode Extensions: No* Seems like it's this one. Are you running VMware as well?

Comment: No, VMware is not installed on my computer.

Comment: In [Microsoft website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx): They say only Hardware requirements: has Second Level Address Translation

Comment: Perhaps http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3190.hyper-v-how-to-fix-bios-errors-enabling-hyper-v.aspx although I'm not sure the information is correct.

Comment: Your CPU should support VM Monitor Mode Extensions (called VT-x on Intel CPUs). Check your BIOS settings, it is probably disabled there. It might not explicitly be called VT-x though...

Comment: yes in My BIOS settings: "Intel Virtualization Technology" (VT-x) is enabled

Comment: in CPU-Z "Instructions" I have: "MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4, SSE4.2, EM64T, VT-x, AES, AVX"

Comment: Thank you very much all ...The issue is resolved but..I don't know what I did exactly! thank you "ta.speot.is" and "Sander Steffann"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Lenovo x201i which was solved by enabling the "**Intel(R) Virtulazation Technology**" and "**Intel(R) VT-d Feature**" options in the BIOS

*Just be aware that the wording of these options may be different for your version of the BIOS*